# System properties overrides local propreties under Windows

Tags: java, spring, properties

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/properties.properties")
public class DataBaseConfig {

@Resource
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    String username = env.getProperty(ConfigurationProperties.DATABASE_USERNAME);
    env.getProperty("username : " + username);

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    //some code
    return dataSource;
}

}
```

I have a problem. When I load my properties with Environment it replaces them with system ones if they have the same name. For example, when I'm trying to load the property "username" from my property file it gets replaced with the system property "username". I know that the environment contains not only my properties, but also other properties from other sources, including system properties, but I don't know how I can influence their order. What is the weirdest thing here is that this code works fine under Linux and loads the properties I need. But under Windows it loads system properties. I have never dealt with such situations, so I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Bean of type Environment. If you have defined @PropertySource as you done, you could make use of @Value("..."). In that case:

```
@Value("${username}")
```

Please try it.

Comment: I know about this way. But the problem is that I have many properties, not the only one. That would be slightly code ugly. The second reason why I still haven't done it is that using Environment is a standard solution and it is given as an example in many spring tutotial, including the official spring tutorial. So I really want to know what causes such an unpredictable result under Windows.

Comment: Why you dont use prefix like db.username to prevent double meaning?